# How to know that new appliance won't trip the circuit?

Tags: kitchens, appliances, circuit-breaker

I'm buying new appliances and want to make sure I won't trip the circuit.

MW/convection is 950 W, 1750 W and 900W for three different functions.  There is 20 Amp circuit for that.

the new stove would have total BTU at 57,000 but the circuit is 20 amp.

We have a toaster on a different circuit that is 1800 W.

Refrigerator is on separate 20 A circuit but I can't find info on Watts of potential new ref rig.

Is this okay?

Comment: Most everything should be fine. A 20A circuit can run at sustained loads of 1920W (80% capacity). I'm not sure about the stove though - you listed it in BTUs, which makes me think it's gas. If it is gas, it should be fine. If it's electric, that's not nearly enough. A 40A 240V would be more appropriate,  and maybe even beefier depending on the actual stove specs.

Comment: Everything you have is FINE. We'd need the actual electrical specs on the stove to know for sure about that though. BTU's is not an electrical rating.

Comment: Here's a post explaining how to perform the calculations: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10622/how-do-you-plan-capacity-for-electrical-circuits

Comment: Hi Sandy! What country are you in? The answer will be quite different if you're wired for 120V or 240V.